# Cannot access Laravel Homestead. How to change SSH keys?

Tags: laravel, ssh, homestead

I cannot access my Laravel Homestead box.  When I run `vagrant up` it eventually fails with this message:

```
SSH auth method: private key Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot {... more}
```

In the VirtualBox UI I can see that the machine is running.  I can not access it with `vagrant ssh` though.  It attempts for a while, then simply returns to the host terminal prompt without any error message.  When I press 'show' in the VirtualBox UI, it takes me to an unfamiliar prompt, `initramfs`.

I am not sure why this happened.  The Linux host was setup only a few months ago with the latest Ubuntu distro, and I have been using Homestead almost every day.  Yesterday I was unable to connect to Bitbucket (over SSH), for some strange reason.  Maybe the two are related?

Based on this thread, https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/homestead-hangs-at-ssh-auth-method-private-key?page=1, I think I should try changing the SSH keys, but how do I do that?  I was not really clear on how the keys worked in the first place.  (Do I need to share the host's public key with the guest?  Or the other way around perhaps?)

Secondly, I don't see how I can change the keys if I can't access the host.

EDIT:

Here are some things I tried on the host:

- Generated a new pair of keys called "homestead".  Updated the authorize key of the Homestead.yaml file.  Also tried adding the new public key under the 'keys' section of Homestead.yaml
- Emptied the known_hosts file
- Removed the private_key file from under the Homestead/.vagrant/.../.... folder
- `ssh vagrant@localhost -p 2222` (it asks for password, but fails to auth)

None of this changed the result.

Answer (score 0):

Regenerate Keys by this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"
```

Comment: That is how I generated the keys (see EDIT section above)